i got an illegal offset type. at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:127
Illegal offset type
whatever my command is it still appear like this.
The error
I'd try the code below from chatgpt. But nothing change. I am totally a beginner and had no clue
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

public function refreshNameLookups()
{
    $this->nameList = [];

    foreach ($this->allRoutes as $route) {
        if ($route->getName()) {
            $name = $route->getName();
            // Log the type of the route name
            Log::info('Route name type: ' . gettype($name));
            $this->nameList[$name] = $route;
        }
    }
}

i also have searched in Youtube but seems like no problem is same with mine.

$name is probably something that is not a string or number

@A.I75, What you have INFO in logs?

PHP error "TypeError: illegal offset type" means you're trying to reference an array index incorrectly. In this case, $name contains a value that can't be used as an array index (i.e., an object, another array, etc) Since $name is the result of $route->getName(), take a look at getName() in \Illuminate\Routing\Route:

public function getName()
{
return $this->action['as'] ?? null;
}

I would take a look at the routes you've defined (e.g., in your routes/web.php file), the problem is mostly like in there.

In your web.php or any routes file, there might be a route where a nonstring data (mostly object) has been passed through the route's ->name() method. Please check all the routes and verify if the names are defined properly.
